# Calculating manhattan and euclidean distance

Tags: r, euclidean-distance

```
my_dist_calculator <- function(a, b, metric = "euclidean"){
 if(metric == "manhattan"){
    mydistance<-function(a,b){
      d<-abs(a-b)
      d<-sum(d)
      return(d)
    }

}else{
    mydistance2<- function(a, b){
      d<-(a-b)^2
      d<-sum(d)
      d<-sqrt(d)
      return(d)
    }

  }

  return(mydistance) 
}
a = c(1.7, 5)
b = c(4, 72)

my_dist_calculator(a, b, metric = "manhattan")
my_dist_calculator(a, b)
```

Hi, I'm new to R and I'm currently trying to compute the euclidean distance and the manhattan distance. The output I'm getting is: environment: 0x10c0bfb60 and bytecode: 0x10caea288. And I don't understand why. Could someone help me to understand what I am doing wrong here? Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. There is already a function in `R` to compute those distances: `dist(x, method="euclidean")` and `dist(x, method="manhattan")`. See `?dist`

Comment: Also you are creating functions inside your function, but you are not using them. You create mydistance, but do not call mydistance(a, b). And function mydistance2 should be mydistance. And the return should be the outcome of the function calls not the function.

Answer (score 3):

When you work in R, you should try to find a function for anything that you want to do. In 99% of cases there's one (maybe not in the base package but somewhere on the internet.

The solution to your problem is `dist` (check the docs using `?dist`) There's the code:

```
a = c(1.7, 5)
b = c(4, 72)
x <- rbind(a,b)
dist(x, method = "euclidean")
dist(x, method = "manhattan")
```

For your code you need to evaluate function in the return statement:

```
my_dist_calculator <- function(a, b, metric = "euclidean"){
  if(metric == "manhattan"){
    mydistance<-function(a,b){
      d<-abs(a-b)
      d<-sum(d)
      return(d)
    }

  }else{
    mydistance<- function(a, b){
      d<-(a-b)^2
      d<-sum(d)
      d<-sqrt(d)
      return(d)
    }

  }

  return(mydistance(a,b)) ### <------ mydistance changed to mydistance(a,b)
}
a = c(1.7, 5)
b = c(4, 72)

my_dist_calculator(a, b, metric = "manhattan")
my_dist_calculator(a, b)
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for functions within functions here. Just calculate `d`, and retun it after the `if....else...` has ended.

```
my_dist_calculator <- function(a, b, metric = "euclidean"){
  if(metric == "manhattan"){
      d<-abs(a-b)
      d<-sum(d)
  }else{
      d<-(a-b)^2
      d<-sum(d)
      d<-sqrt(d)
  }
  return(d) 
}
```

will work

```
a = c(1.7, 5)
b = c(4, 72)
my_dist_calculator(a, b, metric = "manhattan")
# [1] 69.3
my_dist_calculator(a, b)
# [1] 67.03947
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `dist` as others have said before.

But for the sake of the example we can also use `match.arg`

```
my_dist_calculator <- function(a, b, metric = c("euclidean", "manhatten")) {
    metric <- match.arg(metric)
    switch(metric,
           euclidean = sqrt(sum((a - b) ^ 2)),
           manhatten = sum(abs(a - b)))
}

a = c(1.7, 5)
b = c(4, 72)

my_dist_calculator(a, b) # default, i.e. euclidean
# [1] 67.03947

my_dist_calculator(a, b, "manhatten")
# [1] 69.3
```